# Writing JPEG image from BLOB field

Tags: c++, mysql, sdl

I've got a BLOB field in a MySQL database that I need to fetch and write into a `.jpg` file. I already know how to query the database and get the result, but I can't write it into a valid .jpg file. Anyone got any help?

Thanks

Comment: "Write it into"  You are going to have to elaborate here, man.  On disk?  In response to an HTTP request?  Write it where?

Comment: What are you doing now? you just open a file and write the binary data to it.

Comment: @Josh Stodola The goal is to display the image using SDL, but for the best of me I couldn't find a way to display an image from memory, so I'm trying to get the image, save it on disk then open in using SDL_image

Comment: If you can load the image into memory from SQL, why can't you "manually" copy the data onto a surface?

Comment: @Cogwheel I just started learning SDL 4 days ago, I'm a newbie by any measure... All I could find said that load_image only accepted a file name... is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SDL_image, look into [IMG_Load_RW()](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html#SEC12) in particular and [SDL_RWops](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_RWops) in general.